# Wix setting ProgramFiles as default

Tags: wix

I am trying to create an installer using wix. I have this setup

```
<Property Id="INSTALLLOCATION" Secure="yes" />
<Property Id="TARGETDIR" Secure="yes" />
<CustomAction Id='DIRCA_TARGETDIR' Property='TARGETDIR' Value='[ProgramFilesFolder]\[ProductName]' Execute='firstSequence' />
 <Directory Id='TARGETDIR' Name='SourceDir'>
  <Component Id='com_dir_TARGETDIR' Guid='B2F279CF-2E8B-4C04-A5EE-3246B3EEC424' Transitive='no'>
    <CreateFolder Directory='TARGETDIR' />
    <RemoveFolder Id='TARGETDIR' On='uninstall' />
  </Component>
 <Directory Id="INSTALLLOCATION" Name="Client">

    <Component Id="cmpB62155E45B33F7E9F085A10EF7EC9B36A" Guid="75241554-2B0E-41B8-8B1F-2A627FB00B83">
      <File Id="fil7D5D59A00555465436A47FEE7D749560A" KeyPath="yes" Source="$(var.WarDir)\someWar.war" />
    </Component>
```

.....

```
 <Feature Id='ClientInstallation' Title='SomeTitle' Level='1' ConfigurableDirectory='INSTALLLOCATION'>
  <ComponentGroupRef Id='ClientSystemGroup' />

  <Feature Id='SomeId' Title='SomeOtherTitle' Level='1'>
    <ComponentGroupRef Id='SomeSystemGroup' />
  </Feature>
</Feature>
```

...

```
 <InstallExecuteSequence>
  <Custom Action='CA_CreateConfig' Sequence='1' />
  <Custom Action='DIRCA_TARGETDIR' Before='CostInitialize'><![CDATA[TARGETDIR = ""]]></Custom>
```

...
The problem that i am facing is the fact that the default installation directory is not C:\Program Files\ProductName\Client. It is just C:\Client and i can't figure out why.

Answer (score 0):

Try [ProgramFilesFolder][Manufacturer] and skip that backslash after [ProgramFilesFolder] because MSI's folder properties already have a backslash.

Comment: This doesn't seem to change anything. the default value is still c:\Client